# PHPMyAdmin locks up when loading rows

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been using PHPMyAdmin to manage our internal websites for years, and it has always worked really well. However, a few months ago I noticed that it was starting to run slow - specifically when trying to load rows in a table. It took me a few months to sit down and start working on it, and it's to the point where it seems like PHPMyAdmin just gives up - it just gets stuck on loading. And we aren't talking large tables here either - the largest is 26,000 rows, but this happens on all, including ones with say 90 rows. They are InnoDB tables.

Basically, I log into PHPMyAdmin, bring up a database, bring up a table, and hit the arrow for next set of rows, or last set of rows (It's the same either way), and PHPMyAdmin just hangs there saying Loading. It's completely stuck at that point, I need to reload the webpage to do anything else. If I run a SQL query or Search it works fine, and I have not experienced any slowdown on any of our webistes. I even installed Adminer this morning and performed the same tasks and it runs great. So it seems like an issue with PHPMyAdmin.

I did add `$cfg['MaxExactCount'] = 0;` and `$cfg['MaxExactCountViews'] = 0;` to my `config.inc.php` file. I did also run `set global innodb_stats_on_metadata=0` in sql, both suggestions I found on here. Neither has helped.

I was a few versions behind on MySQL, PHP and PHPMyAdmin so I upgraded (although still not to the latest, it seems like jumping from PHP5 to 7 is an involved process). Here is what I'm running:

- Windows 2012 server
- IIS8
- PHP 5.6.30
- MySQL 5.5.54 (I see that PHP sees
  the Client API as mysqlnd-5.0.11-dev if that makes a difference)
- PHPMyAdmin 4.6.6

Any suggestions you might be able to provide to help me try to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This may be a bit too localized a question to find and answer for here, as it basically an invite for "did you try x" comments. It would help if you could find a minimal example to replicate this problem. (I would investigate the exact queries phpmyamdin was creating and see if one creates a bottleneck.)

Comment: Monitor the mysql command line and see if there are any bottlenecks there. Otherwise, you'd have better luck asking the creators of phpmyadmin directly.

Comment: I did just run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` in msql command line and interestingly nothing from phpmyadmin ever appears in there. I actually wrote a quick query of SELECT * FROM 'tickets' ORDER BY id DESC limit 30 inside phpmyadmin (which is similar to what I assume the GUI is doing) and it also got stuck. However, I went and ran that same thing in a PHP file, and displayed the output, and it came up almost immediately.

So it definitely seems like a PHPMyAdmin issue for some reason. I did just check their website and it says to come here for support. Not sure if I need to tag it a certain way

Answer (score 0):

So, I thought I checked this before posting my initial question, but I tried accessing PHPMyAdmin locally on the server and it worked fine. I then tried two other computers and those both work fine. So i don't know what's going on with mine, but it appears to be isolated to my computer. Since I already have plans to re-image it shortly, there's no need to continue looking into this.